# Why is my html table taking up more height than necessary?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table with a bunch of the same image in a single row. The image has a height of 21px but the cells of the table have a rendered height of 25px (in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox).

There's nothing else in the table, and from what I can tell, there are no margins, borders, or padding. So why is my table taller than it needs to be?

Here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/q6zy17dz/

And here's a simple example of the table:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="http://i.imgur.com/b2f5t2B.png"></td>
            <td><img src="http://i.imgur.com/b2f5t2B.png"></td>
            <td><img src="http://i.imgur.com/b2f5t2B.png"></td>
            <td class="datetime"></td>
            <td><img src="http://i.imgur.com/b2f5t2B.png"></td>
            <td><img src="http://i.imgur.com/b2f5t2B.png"></td>
            <td><img src="http://i.imgur.com/b2f5t2B.png"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Bonus question: Is there a way to recreate this layout without using a table (and also without using floats)?

Comment: Why don't you want to use float?

Comment: Since the image is repeated you could always tile it as a background on a div. Just make sure the original image has side padding equal to half the space required between each. Then place another element for your date inside of that div using a set width, margin 0, auto, and a white background.

Comment: @BenL.: I want to keep things simple and not crazy about the clearfix.

Comment: @brian: Thanks for the suggestion, but the repeated image is just an example; in reality it won't be repeated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, an image within a table gets the computed `display:table-cell` property.

You should set `img { display: block; }`

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't know that about the `display` nor how it would make a difference.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it entirely without tables.

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

nav {
    background-color: skyblue;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 22px;
}

.left, .right {
    font-size: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

.left { left: 0; }
.right { right: 0; }
```

```html
<nav>
    <div class="left">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/b2f5t2B.png">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/b2f5t2B.png">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/b2f5t2B.png">
    </div>

    <div class="datetime">foo</div>
    
    <div class="right">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/b2f5t2B.png">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/b2f5t2B.png">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/b2f5t2B.png">
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping with the bonus question!

Answer (score 1):

It is the `line-height` property that makes the height of `<td>` to be 25px. In your example setting a value of 11px or less will make the cells have 21px.

```
td { line-height:11px;}
```

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q6zy17dz/5/).

Comment: If setting the line-height interferes with other things the alternative is make the images block. The default, inline, is what causes the browser to give images extra space, as it does for text. td img {display: block;}

Comment: @brian We could make a CSS rule more specific to avoid interference with other things.

Answer (score 1):

Because the `<img>` tag is rendered like an inline element, similarly to letters. There is space below it is for the descenders.

There are few ways to get rid of that space.

Adjust the vertical alignment:

```
img {vertical-align:top;} /*or*/ img {vertical-align:middle;}
```

Or, set it as a block element:

```
img {display:block;}
```

Or, float it (works in this case, but not recommended):

```
img {float:left;}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    <style type="text/css">
    td { border:solid 1px black; margin:0px; padding:0px; }
    </style>

<div>
<table>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="http://i.imgur.com/b2f5t2B.png"></td>
            <td><img src="http://i.imgur.com/b2f5t2B.png"></td>
            <td><img src="http://i.imgur.com/b2f5t2B.png"></td>
            <td class="datetime">foo</td>
            <td><img src="http://i.imgur.com/b2f5t2B.png"></td>
            <td><img src="http://i.imgur.com/b2f5t2B.png"></td>
            <td><img src="http://i.imgur.com/b2f5t2B.png"></td>
        </tr>
</table>
</div>

<br>
<div>
        <span style="float:left;"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/b2f5t2B.png"></span>
            <span style="float:left;"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/b2f5t2B.png"></span>
            <span style="float:left;"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/b2f5t2B.png"></span>
            <span class="datetime" style="float:left;">foo</span>
            <span style="float:left;"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/b2f5t2B.png"></span>
            <span style="float:left;"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/b2f5t2B.png"></span>
            <span style="float:left;"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/b2f5t2B.png"></span>
</div>
```